# Консольный симулятор входа (типо логин и пароль) не хочет работать: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот ошибка

> File "source_file.py", line 13
>       print ("error password")
>           ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block

Вот код

```
spisok=("netstalker", "hacker", "programmist", "admin")

name=input("enter your username ")
if (name in spisok):
    print ("hello", name)
    password=("qwerty123456")
    passw=input("input password: ")
    if (passw in password):
        print ("complite")
    else:
    print ("error password")

else:
    print ("error")
```

Comment: И в чем вопрос? Непонятен текст ошибки или неясно как добавить к строчке четыре пробела?

Answer (score 2):

```
spisok = ["netstalker", "hacker", "programmist", "admin"]

name = input("Enter your username: ")
if name in spisok:
    print ("hello", name)
    password = "qwerty123456"
    passw = input("Input password: ")
    if passw == password: # == , НО НЕ in
        print("complite")
    else:
        print("error password") # !!!
else:
    print ("error")
```

Ошибка в том, что была пропущена табуляция в теле `else`. Также, если хотите проверить, одинаковы ли 2 значения, используйте оператор `==` вместо `in`. Последний используется для проверки на вхождение в массиве данных.

```
"a" in "abcd" # True
4 in [1,2,3,5] # False
```

Comment: Вы молодец, что заметили еще и ошибку с `passw in password` :)

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка означает что нарушены отступы в коде, а конкретно в строке `print ("error password")`

Так правильно:

```
spisok = ("netstalker", "hacker", "programmist", "admin")

name = input("enter your username ")
if name in spisok:
    print("hello", name)
    password = "qwerty123456"
    passw = input("input password: ")
    if passw == password:
        print("complеte")
    else:
        print("error password")

else:
    print("error")
```

---

**PS.**

Немного причесал код

**PPS.**

Для ввода паролей рекомендую использовать не `input`, а [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/getpass.html):

```
from getpass import getpass

...

passw = getpass("input password: ")
```